# How annotation is processed if my custom annotation is itself annotated?

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-el

I am trying to write my first custom annotation.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.Type)
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole(#exp)")
public @interface CustomPreAutorize{
   String exp();
}
```

The above does not compile as I do not know how can I supply exp value to hasAnyRole method in PreAuthorize.

I have following questions:

1. Can I use SpEL (Spring expression language) over annotation?
2. If I put @CustomPreAutorize on my method will that also call
   @PreAuthorize with exp value with out explicit annotation processor?
3. What is right way to use one annotation with another?